# Run Laravel Mix in Docker Container

Tags: node.js, laravel, docker, npm

I have my application (Laravel) running in a Docker container.

I am now trying to use Laravel Mix to compile my assets. To do this I need node and npm, I am therefore trying to use a separate container to so this.

My Dockerfile just has this:

`FROM node:8`

my docker-compose:

`mix:
    build:
      context: ./docker/mix
      args:
        - DOCKER_ENV=${DOCKER_ENV}
    container_name: mix
    volumes:
      - ${PROJECT_PATH}/src:/srv/app
    environment:
      - DOCKER_ENV=${DOCKER_ENV}
      - APP_DEBUG=${APP_DEBUG}`

When I try to build I keep getting Exit Code 0 from this container.

I just want a container to build my assets on, am I doing the right thing.:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#running-mix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a process running to keep the container alive. One common approach is to run a shell script or command continuously.  Trying adding this to the end of the dockerfile:

```
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Comment: That is working, I can SSH on now and run ```npm run dev``` but I am getting ``` Error: Cannot find module '../' ```

Answer (score 3):

We ran into the same problem when trying to run laravel mix in a docker node image. either the image stopped running or it couldn't install the node_modules.

After a bit of digging we found a solution in using entrypoints, this can be used to overwrite the default run command of the docker image.

We created an entrypoint which calls npm run watch-poll on docker-compose up -d, the entrypoint file looks like this:

```
#file:docker/init-scripts/node_start.sh 
#!/bin/sh

set -e

echo 'running prestart node script'
echo 'running npm install'
npm install

echo 'initialization done, start watching'
npm run watch-poll
```

Which is then called in docker-compose.yml like this:

```
  node:
    image: node:10-alpine
    container_name: node
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    volumes:
      - ./htdocs:/usr/src/app
      - ./docker/init-scripts/:/init-scripts/
    entrypoint:
      - /init-scripts/node_start.sh
    depends_on:
      - 'app'
```

We placed the entire solution on github, found here: https://github.com/jva91/docker-laravel-mix